# Sencha Touch 2 - Add javascript to views

Tags: javascript, view, sencha-touch

How do I use JS in a Sencha Touch view?

```
Ext.define('project.view.viewexample', {
extend: 'Ext.Panel',
xtype: 'asd',

config: {
    styleHtmlContent: true, 
    scrollabe: 'vertical',
    title: 'TITLE!',
    Html: '<html>code and also JS?'
}   
});
```

I have htmlcode which includes jscode (within Script-tags). It doesn't seem to work to use in this matter, am I right? I've also tried to use tpl, but it doesn't change anything.

Anyone know how to properly use JS? A somewhat better alternative would be to use it within the controller, but in that case I don't know how to pass the data.

**EDIT:**
I've come somewhat closer to a solution I think. This code below is clearly wrong, but maybe someone can see what I'm doing wrong:

```
Ext.define('projext.view.viewexample', {
extend: 'Ext.Panel',
xtype: 'gps',

config: {
    styleHtmlContent: true, 
    scrollabe: 'vertical',
    title: 'GPS',
    tpl: 'Här var det GPS'
},
constructor: function() {
    this.getPosition();
},
getPosition: function() {
    var geo = Ext.create('Ext.util.Geolocation', {
        autoUpdate: false,
        listeners: {
            locationupdate: function(geo) {
                alert('New latitude: ' + geo.getLatitude());
            },
            locationerror: function(geo, bTimeout, bPermissionDenied, bLocationUnavailable, message) {
                if(bTimeout){
                    alert('Timeout occurred.');
                } else {
                    alert('Error occurred.');
                }
            }
        }
    });
    geo.updateLocation();
}
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `html` config needs to be lower-case.

```
Ext.define('project.view.viewexample', {
    extend: 'Ext.Panel',

    styleHtmlContent: true, 
    scrollabe: 'vertical',
    title: 'TITLE!',
    html: 'define your html'
});
```

Comment: Thank you, I didn't know that. However, its not the answer of my question which is where do I put my jscode?

Comment: What kind of JsCode? You updated your OP and that is a good example. Note that you need to use the `this` keyword in this line: `constructor: function() {this.getPosition();},`

Comment: I tried to add "this." before the methodcall in the constructor. But I get "ncaught ReferenceError: getPosition is not defined". Do you know why?

Comment: use `initComponent` instead of `constructor`. I'm not really sure tho ;)